# Перенос символов UItextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

У меня есть UITextView в таблице, проблема в том, что только на iPhone 4 ,если писать 2 символа, то они отображатся вот так

[image: Не так]

а должна вот так

[image: Как надо]

Пробовал менять уже и высоту и ширину.
Текст задается следующим методом

```
-(NSAttributedString *)chatStringsMy:(NSString *)string
{
NSRange rangeBold = [string rangeOfString:string];

NSDictionary *dictBoldText = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0],
                               
                               NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]
                               };

NSMutableAttributedString *mutAttrTextViewString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
[mutAttrTextViewString setAttributes:dictBoldText range:rangeBold];

return mutAttrTextViewString;
```

}

Уже все перепробовал, не могу понять почему именно на 4 iPhone такое происходит iOS 7.1.2

Comment: Сделайте поддержку устройств с iPhone 4s) P.S. Простите за offtop, если не секрет - в каком xcode, mac os и на какой машине работаете?

Comment: @Denis xcode version 7.2 (7C68)
Mac mini (середина 2010 г.)
OS Capitan 10.11.3